# Using Angular Material ToolTip but can't select text on element beneath it

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, angular-material, tooltip

I have an Angular Material tooltip used to display information when hovering over a columns cells in a table element. On top of this functionality I also require users to be able to select the text and highlight it from the table element so they can copy and paste it.

Because I am using Angular Material tooltip and ::ng-deep to display it over top of the column, it creates an overlay over the existing DOM elements so I can't select the text in the column. Is there anyway around this? Do I have to edit the matToolTip class?

Thanks!

My ultimate solution will be to use a more native tooltip elements that will be part of the DOM and not block users from selecting the text however this isn't as pretty so it's my last resort.

```
edit.component.html

import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';

<ng-container matColumnDef="DepartmentName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
        <td
          mat-cell
          *matCellDef="let row"
          [matTooltip]="getTooltipMissingDepartments(row)"
          matTooltipClass="missing-mds-tooltip"
        >
          {{ row?.DepartmentName }}
        </td>
      </ng-container>

edit.component.scss

::ng-deep .missing-mds-tooltip {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Users should  be able to hover over the column and see a tooltip, as well as highlight the text in the table for that column.

Answer (score 8):

To get this working, I added the following provider to my [custom NgModule](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-3-import-the-component-modules) that imports all of the Angular Material components I use in my app, which I then import as necessary

```
import { MAT_HAMMER_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  // imports, exports, etc. go here

  providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_HAMMER_OPTIONS,
      useValue: {
        cssProps: {
          userSelect: true
        }
      },
    },
  ],
})
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. It does seem to work, but I'm not sure if it has any side effects. I have not noticed any when using it in a standard browser-based Angular application but have not used it on mobile or other platforms.

Comment: Using `MAT_HAMMER_OPTIONS` is now marked as deprecated: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/core/gestures/gesture-config.ts#L48

Comment: @JanPospíšil - thanks for the update! It looks like it will be dropped in 10.0, so it's still usable (albeit deprecated) until then

Comment: @Kabb5 Still wasn't able to find any non deprecated replacement tho... :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an open issue about this :
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8817

Instead of giving the user the option to copy, You can force copy the text to the clipboard when hover the tool tip automatically by using :  [ngx-clipboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-clipboard)

Comment: So from what I can tell, this open issue is about selecting the actual text on the tooltip, I want to select the text on the tooltip beneath it. On the table element, but the overlay is blocking that element.